# Get values onResume method

Tags: android, fragment

I have a `recyclerView` on `onCreateView` method. But I have to fill with values that i receive on `onResume` method. The problem is `onCreateView` start before `onResume`. What can I do?

Comment: post your `Fragment` code

Comment: You can create a global Recyclerview instance and initialize it in onCretaeView and put values in onResume of fragment life cycle.

Comment: postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in a right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreateView is in adapter, and you can create an adapter in onResume, 
and then `setAdapter` for recyclerview inside onResume.

Also to avoid creating it every time you can use some kind of boolean local variable which will tell you if the adapter was already created.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adapterNotCreated) {
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, data)
        daysRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        daysRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the data of the adapter by calling notifidatasetchsnged in onResune, instead of setAdapter, which should be done in onCreateView